# SQL Server - List employee with manager and above

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a dataset like this (I'm using employee and manager because it's a nice example):

```
EmployeeID | ManagerID | Role          | ...
1          | NULL      | CEO
2          | 1         | Manager
3          | 1         | Manager
5          | 2         | Team-Leader
6          | 2         | Team-Leader
7          | 3         | Team-Leader
8          | 2         | Employee
9          | 5         | Employee
10         | 6         | Employee
11         | 6         | Employee
12         | 7         | Employee
```

I would like to list the `EmployeeID`'s with everyone that has a role above him. This is the result I'm aiming for:

```
EmployeeID | ManagerID
12         | 7
12         | 3
12         | 1
12         | NULL
11         | 6
11         | 2
11         | 1
11         | NULL
....
9          | 5
9          | 2
9          | 1
9          | NULL
```

So if I were to use a `where` on the `EmployeeID` in the result, I could get the employee and everyone above his ranks that he's responsible to.

I tried to work it out with a recursive cte, but that didn't seem to work out at all.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Share your query please.

Comment: I searched [SQL Server get all managers of employee](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+Server+get+all+managers+of+employee) and found this, [SQL Query to get recursive count of employees under each manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19690325/3484879), which looks very similar to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with cte1(EmployeeID, ManagerID) as
(
select EmployeeID, max(ManagerID)
from Employees
group by EmployeeID
union all
select t2.EmployeeID, t1.ManagerID
from Employees t1
join cte1 t2 on t2.ManagerID = t1.EmployeeID
)
select * from cte1
order by EmployeeID desc, ManagerID desc
```

Comment: This does not complete. Adding OPTION (MAXDOP 0) causes it to run forever.

Comment: @AlanBurstein I just re-ran it successfully with the sample data successfully. My SQL Server version is: SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64) Jun 15 2019 00:26:19 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 18362: ) (Hypervisor).

Comment: Yep - My bad... Copy and paste error with the sample data. I had duplicate employee keys.

Comment: @AlanBursteinThanks, you made my day.